# How to return customized value from REST Web services

Tags: c#, web-services

Im using a REST web service in my project that it's return values are in json like this:

`[{"MsgID":"92817137","Status":"0","SendTime":"2014-06-11 14:17:40","DeliverTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]`

but I dont need to all of that, I need just "Statues" tag. how can I do that?

my code is like this:

```
    private void btnCheckStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri address = new Uri("http://www.asanak.ir/webservice/v1rest/msgstatus");

        // Create the web request
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set type to POST
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Create the data we want to send
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.Append("username=" + textUserName.Text.Trim());
        data.Append("&password=" + textPassword.Text.Trim());
        data.Append("&msgid=" + textMsgId.Text.Trim());

        // Create a byte array of the data we want to send
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());

        // Set the content length in the request headers
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        // Write data
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        // Get response
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            textResult.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

I want my return value be like this: `"Status":"0"`

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by return value? This method (btnCheckStatus_Click) doesn't return anything - do you want to read the value of Status from the web service?

Comment: @Axarydax yeah, I want to read only Status Value from web service... but by above code, I read all of that...

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot change the webservice's method to make it only returns values  you need, the only way is to customize the response in your code.

```
// Get response
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    //add your code here to customize the return value
    var array = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
    var jObject = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
    jObject.Add("Status", array[0].Value<string>("Status"));

    textResult.Text = jObject.ToString();

}
```